# Как правильно: профилактика здоровья или профилактика заболеваний?

Tags: выбор-слов, общие-вопросы, лексическая-сочетаемость

Как правильно: профилактика психического здоровья или профилактика психических заболеваний?

Answer (score 2):

Оба  выражения правильные, но они имеют разное содержание.

Из словаря: ПРОФИЛАКТИКА, -и; ж. [от греч. prophylaktikós - предохранительный] **Совокупность предупредительных мероприятий**, **направленных на сохранение и укрепление нормального состояния, порядка**. П. заболеваний. П. преступности.

Итак, профилактика – это мероприятия. Профилактика здоровья – это мероприятия для укрепления здоровья (здоровый образ жизни). Профилактика заболеваний – это мероприятия для предупреждения   заболеваний (медосмотры и т.д.). Это разные мероприятия, поэтому и названия у них разные.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, нужно говорить "**профилактика заболеваний**", а "профилактика здоровья" – неверно.

На сайте Минздрава России слово "профилактика" употребляется только в смысле "профилактика заболеваний", а для здоровья используется оборот "профилактика в сфере охраны здоровья".

ПРОФИЛАКТИКА
Наука, исследующая условия предотвращения и предохранения людей от заболеваний.
(Источник: «Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка». Чудинов А.Н., 1910)

ПРОФИЛАКТИКА
предупреждение наступления болезни мерами, противодействующими заболеванию. Профилактические средства - меры против заражения к.-л. болезнью. Проф. меры разделяются на общие и частные. Обществ. проф. меры называются санитарными.
(Источник: «Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка». Павленков Ф., 1907)

ПРОФИЛАКТИКА
учение о предупреждении заболеваний.
(Источник: «Полный словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в употребление в русском языке». Попов М., 1907)

[Словарь сининимов](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-70250.htm):

Профилактика – предотвращение, предупреждение, предохранение

[Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_167):

В самом значении этого слова заключен смысловой компонент «предупреждение»: предупреждение заболеваний, предупреждение преступности.

И на сайте [Минздрава России](https://www.rosminzdrav.ru/documents/7025-federalnyy-zakon-ot-21-noyabrya-2011-g-323-fz-ob-osnovah-ohrany-zdorovya-grazhdan-v-rossiyskoy-federatsii) слово "профилактика" употребляется только в смысле "профилактика заболеваний", а для здоровья используется оборот "профилактика в сфере охраны здоровья"

В Нацкорпусе "профилактика здоровья" встречается только один раз.

Answer (score -1):

В обычном понимании этого слова — делают профилактику заболеваний. Когда ничего не болит, у нас не принято беспокоиться.